# In the age of people getting as many avatars and social profiles as they want, can we really define death?

Tags: death, virtual-reality, social-media

When we get the chance to create social profiles, gaming avatars, alternative virtual and social personalities, is it possible to actually die someday?

Comment: Of course, who is populating those accounts with content if you are dead?

Comment: Are you talking about chat-bots that you program or train to act like you online? They will continue operating, but they will not get any new input from the human owner, so they will be viewed as a talking tombstone, or maybe is "children" of the original human. But nobody will consider them to equal the actual human.

Comment: The diagnosis of death is a matter of definition for a given purpose. Death in a hospital environment is routinely tested for by a clear set of rules and tests. You can define death in a different way if you wish but you will have to specify precisely what *you* mean. “When I use a word,” Humpty Dumpty said, in rather a scornful tone, “it means just what I choose it to mean—neither more nor less.” “The question is,” said Alice, “whether you can make words mean so many different things.” “The question is,” said Humpty Dumpty, “which is to be master—that's all.”

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!  We're glad you could join us!  When you have a moment, please [click here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388) to learn more about our culture and take our [tour]. [SE is not a discussion forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums/92110#92110).  The SE Q&A model is one-specific-question/one-best-answer.  What are you actually asking?  Obviously (and very objectively), the account owner will (and does) die.  What, then, is your specific not-a-discussion question?

Comment: Avatars and social media profiles aren't what make you alive. Being alive is curious balance of mundane biology and the metaphysically spiritual. Please take a look at the [help] and [tour] and edit your question in such a way that there is clear worldbuilding context and a single question that focuses on a single worldbuilding issue or problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It is possible to die. Both online and offline.

Now your obviously interested in how long a persons online presence remains after their physical death. They say that a person isn't truly dead until they have been forgotten. The problem is, no one will live forever and in an age where the next social trend drives your popularity, major celebrities and bots will soon be forgotten as well, especially as we invent new media platforms and commercial experiences (looking at VR here).

Firstly, you have to remember that if you put something on the internet, someone somwhere is paying for the storage that thing takes up. It can be a massive data center owned by facebook or a small home server you setup yourself. Maybe even an infected computer a virus hijacked. The lifetime or your bot, profile or avatar is only going to last so long. Sure it might live out the next several decades on a facebook server, but it too will eventually be decommissioned (there will eventually be billions of dead profiles on facebook that they will clean up because the profiles will be of no value to them anymore).

To stay relevant you need to make your presence known. This is hard for bots. Bots can target certain forums or websites and behave in certain ways (the open self learning ones are very easily skewed). Eventually the popularity and purpose of websites change. Catchas are introduced, new API's and code based interactions are put in place. Technology keeps moving, but that Bot which keeps chatting away doesnt. Its stuck in time and when the technology moves, it will be left behind (e.g. If we move into VR and the internet shifts in that direction, your chat based bots aren't going to work).

Now the important part is that you might be famous, have made a mark on history. You could be Jesus. But eventually, we will reach a stage when humans become extinct. If you look at the history of the world and represented it in a 24 hour clock, we appear roughly 2 minutes before the 24 hours is up. If you look at the history of the internet, its going to be even less significant than that. We are an insignificant speck to the universe and eventually we will all die out and so will the memory of you.

Note: There is also the issue of the memory of you being twisted and manipulated into something that wasn't you. Sort of like the building a new boat using the old boats philosophical problem. Eventually the representation of you will no longer be you. It will be someone different with your name and face plastered over it.